# Visualizing data from json files

Tags: json, graph, statistics, visualization, grafana

Suppose I had files with names of the following scheme:
2023-03-11_15-05-01.json (i.e. yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss.json)

Those files contain data of the following scheme:

```
[
  {
    "price": 2.71,
    "name": "Salespoint1",
    "address": "Somestreet",
    "Nr": "8"
  },
  {
    "super": 2.81,
    "name": "Salespoint2",
    "address": "Someotherstreet",
    "Nr": "34"
  },
  {
    "super": 4.14,
    "name": "Salespoint3",
    "address": "Thirdstreet",
    "Nr": "14 - 16"
  },
  {
    "super": 3.12,
    "name": "Salespoint4",
    "address": "Bla Ave",
    "Nr": "102"
  }
]
```

I'm looking for a way to visualize this data easily in a graph that would display the prices, minimum, maximum, average, over time. The file is being generated every 30 mins. The file name contains the timestamp of the data. I have next to no programming experience.

A simple solution would be generated image file.

A sophisticated solution would be a Grafana dashboard. I have a free grafana.net account, but I do not know how to upload the data. The data is being generated on a very small Linux VM.

Do you guys have ideas?

Comment: Grafana itself is visualization platform, it doesn't store your data. It queries data from elsewhere (prometheus, influx, mysql, etc.) 
Assuming your files stored locally you wouldn't have some obvious way to let public grafana access them.

Comment: As of manual visualization, you'll have to read all your files, convert data from them to some kind of time-series and visualize this series. Selection of language is on you, but if you have no obvious preference, you could try python, as it is quite popular for such tasks, novice friendly and has a lot of manuals, articles and so forth.

Comment: @markalex To your first comment: grafana.net (or .com) offers some sort of storage, it seems, I just don't know what to do with the files. To your second comment: Probably....not :D Thanks for your thoughts ;)